# Issues with showing french accents from my Database

Tags: php, database, utf-8, odbc

I am connection to a Filemaker DB through ODBC, and some data contains accents such as é or è. These characters appear as "?" right now, which is a bit of a problem. Here is what my code looks like:

```
$connection = odbc_connect($dsn, $username, $password, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";

$res = odbc_exec($connection,$sql);

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){

$x++;


   $values= ($x . ":  Customer:". $row['Customer'] . "\n");

   print($values);

}

odbc_free_result($res);
odbc_close($connection);
```

I tried a few things, such as adding 'charset=utf-8' in the header, but nothing seems to work so far. I'm pretty sure I need to include utf-8 somewhere, I just haven't found examples with odbc similar to my code online. Thanks!

Comment: you need to make sure the ENTIRE rendering chain is using the same charset. that means your php->oracle connection, the tables/fields inside oracle, the oracle->php connection, the output from php to the client, etc...

Comment: I rolled back the last edit as it removed the question without actually deleting the question. Please do not mutilate your own questions this way. It is 1) not helpful for others and 2) might lead to downvotes. Either fully delete your question, or leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect using the correct encoding. You can determine the correct encoding with the following query:

```
SELECT hex(CustomerCustomer) FROM Table1;
```

Match the hex code of the offending character with the target encodings, most likely `latin1` and `UTF-8`. If you cannot identify the hex codes, then paste the output here and I will identify it for you.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC use a encode type called WIN1252.

Try it:

```
mb_convert_encoding($value,'UTF-8','Windows-1252');
```

i've used it to do the opposite from win1252 to utf8 by this way should works to.. Let me know

So try it:
Use the function mb_detect_encoding(). If the function doesn't exist try this code.

```
if ( !function_exists('mb_detect_encoding') ) {


function mb_detect_encoding ($string, $enc=null, $ret=null) {

    static $enclist = array(
        'UTF-8', 'ASCII',
        'ISO-8859-1', 'ISO-8859-2', 'ISO-8859-3', 'ISO-8859-4', 'ISO-8859-5',
        'ISO-8859-6', 'ISO-8859-7', 'ISO-8859-8', 'ISO-8859-9', 'ISO-8859-10',
        'ISO-8859-13', 'ISO-8859-14', 'ISO-8859-15', 'ISO-8859-16',
        'Windows-1251', 'Windows-1252', 'Windows-1254',
        );

    $result = false;

    foreach ($enclist as $item) {
        $sample = iconv($item, $item, $string);
        if (md5($sample) == md5($string)) {
            if ($ret === NULL) { $result = $item; } else { $result = true; }
            break;
        }
    }

return $result;
}
```

Source: 
[PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)